# Big(O) computational complexity of super-resolution algorithm

Tags: computer-vision, big-o

I am trying to implement a super-resolution algorithm to increase the resolution of a single input image, but need something that is relatively inexpensive in terms of complexity.

I have come across Yang et al. Super Resolution algorithm using sparse representation.

`http://www.ifp.illinois.edu/~jyang29/papers/TIP10-SR.pdf`

what is its computational complexity in bigO notation?

Comment: Judging from a quick scan of the paper, that's not an easy thing to determine. A lot depends on implementation details (e.g., how one solves the constrained optimization problem that's part of the algorithm). However, if you are concerned with real-world performance, a big-O answer won't tell you much. Why? Because everything depends on the coefficients. That's why IRL everyone still uses the Simplex method (with exponential complexity) instead of interior-point methods (with polynomial complexity); in practice, the latter are much more expensive except for gigantic problems.

Comment: Thanks for the response @TedHopp, interesting